# What are the best medicinal plants that can be grown in a backyard or kitchen garden?

Tags: gardening, diy, health, survival

The ones that I already have:

- Chicory: Known for its digestive benefits, chicory can help stimulate appetite and aid in digestion.
- Yarrow: Yarrow has antiseptic and anti-inflammatory properties, making it useful for treating minor wounds and skin irritations.
- California Poppy: Often used as a natural remedy for anxiety, insomnia, and mild pain relief.
- Marshmallow: Marshmallow root is known for its soothing properties, particularly for sore throats and coughs.
- Chamomile: Chamomile is well-known for its calming effects and can be used to alleviate stress, anxiety, and insomnia.
- Evening Primrose: Evening primrose oil is believed to have anti-inflammatory properties and may help alleviate symptoms of eczema and rheumatoid arthritis.
- Lavender: Lavender has calming effects and can be used to alleviate stress, anxiety, and insomnia.
- Echinacea: Believed to boost the immune system and help fight off colds and infections.
- Calendula: Used topically for its anti-inflammatory and wound-healing properties.
- Feverfew: Often used to prevent migraines and alleviate symptoms of headaches and arthritis.

These plants offer a range of medicinal benefits, from soothing digestive issues to promoting relaxation and boosting the immune system, making them valuable additions to any backyard and kitchen garden.

But I'm interested, is there anything else I can add to my garden?

Comment: Welcome to Sustainable Living! Do you have any particular purpose or ailment in mind? There are hundreds if not thousands of plants that can be regarded as medicinal, so asking for "the best" makes the scope of your question very wide and any answer would be incomplete.
I also take it you want to grow them yourselves, so perhaps you can tell us something about the climate or conditions of your backyard?